# Merge Sort not merging properly C++

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I have written a program for merge sort and The program works fine until at a point of merging that it doesn't merge properly

Here is the 3 functions that does the merge sort. I can't find the problem

```
void mergeSort(int A[], int tmp[], int n)
{
mergeSort(A, tmp, 0, n);
merge(A,tmp,0,n);}

void mergeSort(int A[],int tmp[], int left, int right){
if (right-left<2)
    return;


int mid;

if (left < right)
{
    mid= ((left+right)/2);

    mergeSort(A, tmp, mid+1, right);
    merge (A, tmp, mid+1, right-1);

    mergeSort(A, tmp, left ,mid);
    merge (A, tmp, left, mid);
}

return;
}
void merge(int A[], int tmp[], int left, int right)
{
int k=left;
int start=left;
int mid= ((right+left)/2)+1;
int leftEnd= mid-1;
int numElemet= (right-left);

while ((left<=leftEnd) &&(mid<=right))
{
    if (A[left]<= A[mid])
    {
        tmp[k] = A[left];
        k++;
        left++;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp[k] = A[mid];
        k++;
        mid++;
    }
}
while (left<= leftEnd)
{
    tmp[k]= A[left];
    left++;
    k++;
}
while(mid<= right)
{
    tmp[k]= A[mid];
    mid++;
    k++;
}
for (int i=start;i<k; i++)
{
A[i]= tmp[i];
}
}
```

So the program gets in the array splits it fine but when it gets to going back recursion misses some of the merges and half of the array doesn't get merged on in the right place.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be double-careful about the boundaries while manipulating arrays.

1.
Your code:

```
mergeSort(A, tmp, mid+1, right);
merge (A, tmp, mid+1, right-1);
```

Merge sort is a `Divide and conquer` method. The range of numbers being divided and conquered should be the same. Which part of the above code do you think has a mistake?

2.`int numElemet= (right-left);` is not used and should be deleted, further more, the # of elements should be `right-left+1`.

3.

```
for (int i=start;i<k; i++)
{
    A[i]= tmp[i];
}
```

The k is not the desired value, try find where the error is before this piece of code.

4.
A piece of advice:
Use tab to indent the code in order to improve readibility. It's good for both you and the people reading your code. And use `cout` to check the values of variables in case the code doesn't perform as you desired.